# RDS Data API BatchExecute taking significantly longer than standard connection

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, rds-data-api

I have an AWS Lambda function that needs to insert several thousand rows of data into an RDS PostgreSQL database within a Serverless Cluster. Previously I used a normal database connection using psycopg2, but I switched to the RDS Data API in order to improve performance. However, using the Data API, `BatchExecute` exceeds the 5 minute lambda limit and still fails to commit the transaction in this time. Meanwhile, the psycopg2 solution, which uses a different transfer protocol, inserts all data in under 30 seconds.

Why is this possible? Shouldn't the Data API give superior performance as it doesn't need to establish a connection? Can I change any settings to make the RDS Data API perform suitably?

I don't believe I am reaching any of the [data size limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html#data-api.calling.cli.batch-execute-statement), because the lambda times out rather than explicitly throwing an error. Also, I know that the connection is succeeding, as other small queries are able to execute successfully.

Comment: The Data API does establish a connection behind the scenes. And as far as I can tell, it creates a new connection (with all the overhead that implies) for every request. Plus, it's adding the overhead of a web request, plus retrieving connection information from Secrets Manager.

Comment: If you must use the Data API for whatever reason, use `BatchExecuteStatement` to insert multiple rows at the same time. And note that Lambda actually has a 15 minute max timeout.

Comment: I am using `BatchExecute`.